# Why does my website think the $http request is cross domain?

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, http, cors

In my website I'm calling to a php page at http://domain.com/angulartest/js/services/index.php

from a service in the same folder.

```
app.factory('vakmannen', ['$http', function($http) {
return $http.get('http://www.domain.com/angulartest/js/services/index.php')
.success(function(data) {
    return data;
})
.error(function(err) {
    return err;
}); 
}]);
```

and this is my php

```
<?php
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://www.domain.com/angulartest/");

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "XXXXX";
$password = "XXXXX";
$dbname = "XXXXX";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$sql = "SELECT * FROM XXXX";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
while($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
            $myArray[] = $row;
    }
    echo json_encode($myArray);
?>
```

But every time the $http.get runs Firefox tells me the CORS header isn't right, I've tried it on Chrome too but to no avail.

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: www.domain.com is not the same as domain.com!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the angular app is in the same folder, you can use relative URLs. You can even remove the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header.

```
app.factory('vakmannen', ['$http', function($http) {
return $http.get('/angulartest/js/services/index.php')
.success(function(data) {
    return data;
})
.error(function(err) {
    return err;
}); 
}]);
```

Comment: Ofcourse! relative paths! Will accept as the awnser when time permits.